# Cannot populate a combobox with System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, list, combobox

I added a System.Collections.Generic.List to the application settings.

In my form, I'd like to populate a combobox with the list.

So I try to do:

```
comboBox.DataSource = Properties.Settings.Default.list;
```

However, when I run the program, I get the following error in Settings.Designer.cs:

> System.ArgumentException: The property "list" cannot be created from default values. The error message: Error in the XML document (1, 1).

(Sorry it may not be the exact same message because it does not say it in English, but I tried my best to translate it)

The above code worked for a StringCollection, but it does not work now for a list. Why?

Also worth mentioning is that if I do not try to populate the combobox, it does not throw the error.

Comment: How is this list populated?  The error is talking about XML, but there is no XML in the question.

Comment: The error is talking about the Settings.settings file, which, in reality is an XML file. (Right click -> View Code). It basicaly contains the settings you add in the Settings designer.